# Cutting tzitzis strings

Tags: halacha, tzitzis

I'm pretty sure I once saw the Mishna Brura talk about how it's best not to cut tzitzis with metal and that there's a custom to cut tzitzis strings with your teeth. But now, although I keep searching through O.C. Siman 11, I can't seem to find it. Can anyone come up with *marei mekomos*?

Comment: would a ceramic blade knife be also an acceptable alternative to teeth and metal? Ceramic blades are made out of zirconium dioxide (ZrO2)

Comment: @TzitzMan, welcome to Judaism.SE! If you have a follow-up question, please consider [posting it](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) as a question, rather than as an answer. Also, please consider registering your account, which will give you access to more of the site's features, including leaving comments like this one.

Comment: @TzitzMan Yes, you can use a ceramic blade, and it is how most companies today cut their tzizit.

Comment: @Ben ShmuelBrill gave you the Mare Makom in the Mishna Berura

Answer (score 7):

Look in  Mogen Avraham sif katan 18 and [Shulchan Aruch Harav (11:24)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25072&st=&pgnum=83&hilite=) where it says that one should not cut Tzitzis with metal (like a Mizbeyach (Altar)) but cut them with his teeth.

It's also in the [Mishna Brura s"k 61](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=44&hilite=)

Comment: I was also told a flame is OK; I use a candle. Easier and neater than teeth.

Comment: What did the rishonim hold? Was this discussed before the achronim?

Answer (score 1):

The Yalqut Yosef may write that it is better not, but if one needs to he may. I think the Ben Ish Hai brings the Rashash who writes to refrain from doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Kaf HaHaim Palagi ([Siman 10:12](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7882&st=&pgnum=140)) writes that one should not cut the Sisit with metal because of "Lo tanif aleyhen barzel." See Kisur HaShela 53b.

Comment: What did the rishonim hold? Was this discussed before the achronim?

Answer (score 0):

Shulchan Aruch HaRav Chapter 11 section 24

> It is preferable to make a point of not cutting tzitzis with a knife, recalling the command, “Do not raise iron upon them.” Instead, one should bite them off with the teeth.

(From [Chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3269361/jewish/Shulchan-Aruch-Chapter-11-Laws-Relating-to-Threads-of-Tzitzis.htm))